# Excel - Error when trying to loop through workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

Good day friends,
I'm receiving an error whenever I try to loop through all open workbooks in order to copy and paste to a master workbook.
For the life of me I can't figure out how to rectify it, could any of you kindly assist?

```
Sub LoopCopyPaste()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Lastrow As Long
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
            If wb.Name <> "MasterDatabase.xlsx" & "MacrosExcelFile.xls" Then
                Lastrow = wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
                wb.Worksheets(1).Range("B7:J" & Lastrow).Copy
                ''
                Windows("MasterDatabase.xlsx").Activate
                Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
            End If
    Next wb
End Sub
```

The error is "1004, Application-defined or object-defined error", and it points to the "Lastrow = wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row" sentence.
What can I do to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't looked closely enough to see whether it could be related to your issue, but `If wb.Name <> "MasterDatabase.xlsx" & "MacrosExcelFile.xls" Then` is equivalent to `If wb.Name <> "MasterDatabase.xlsxMacrosExcelFile.xls" Then`.  You want `If wb.Name <> "MasterDatabase.xlsx" And wb.Name <>  "MacrosExcelFile.xls" Then`

Comment: I'm guessing your problem will actually be related to the unqualified `Rows.Count` and `Range`.  Try changing them to include the spreadsheet that you are referring to.  (The first one would be `Lastrow = wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(wb.Worksheets(1).Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row`, and that's **probably** the one casuing the problem, but the later one should be changed too to be safe.)  Oops - didn't read your question far enough - that unqualified `Rows.Count` is definitely your issue.

Comment: This was definitely the problem! I looked at the code a thousand times and couldn't figure that one out, thanks a lot friend!

Answer (score 1):

```
If wb.Name <> "MasterDatabase.xlsx" And wb.Name <> "MacrosExcelFile.xls" Then
```

Try changing that. I will update this answer when I test it a bit more.

Comment: That was another issue I didn't catch ;) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

SalvadorVayshun is correct

```
If wb.Name <> "MasterDatabase.xlsx" And wb.Name <> "MacrosExcelFile.xls" Then
```

Here is how I would refactor the code

```
Sub LoopCopyPaste()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name <> "MasterDatabase.xlsx" And wb.Name <> "MacrosExcelFile.xls" Then

            With wb.Worksheets(1)
                .Range("B7:J7", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Copy
            End With

            With Workbooks("MasterDatabase.xlsx").Worksheets(1)
                .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
            End With

        End If
    Next wb
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

### Values only

```
Sub LoopCopyPaste()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Data
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name <> "MasterDatabase.xlsx" And wb.Name <> "MacrosExcelFile.xls" Then

            With wb.Worksheets(1)
                Data = .Range("B7:J7", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Value
            End With

            With Workbooks("MasterDatabase.xlsx").Worksheets(1)
                .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)).Value = Data
            End With

        End If
    Next wb
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

### Values and Formulas

```
Sub LoopCopyPaste()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Data
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name <> "MasterDatabase.xlsx" And wb.Name <> "MacrosExcelFile.xls" Then

            With wb.Worksheets(1)
                Data = .Range("B7:J7", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Formula
            End With

            With Workbooks("MasterDatabase.xlsx").Worksheets(1)
                .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)).Formula = Data
            End With

        End If
    Next wb
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```